# Users cannot update profile info

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to let users change their profile information but instead of changing the existing profile, `form.save()` saves it as a new entry under the same user. Example:

> Bio would say 'What's up', they go to edit and no visible info is changed but another set of info is put in my userprofile table.

I tried using SQL commands and it returned something about an error near 'IT', which isn't in my code. I've tried getting my `user.profile` and then trying to edit the info through that with:

```
user.profile.sex = form.cleaned_data['sex']
```

I've looked through the docs and the only thing I found that makes sense is `Model.save(force_update=True)` but where would I put it in my view and how could I link it to the user?

View with the SQL I tried...

```
@login_required
def edit_prof(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EPIF(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            user_id = request.user.id
            conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
            cur = conn.cursor()

            sex = form.cleaned_data['sex'] 
            dob = form.cleaned_data['dob']
            r_stat = form.cleaned_data['relationship_stat']
            locale = form.cleaned_data['location']
            bio = form.cleaned_data['bio']
            cur.execute('''
            UPDATE profs_customuserprofile
            SET sex = {}, dob = {}, relationship_stat = {},
            location = {}, bio = {}
             WHERE ID = {};
             '''.format(sex, dob, r_stat, locale, bio, user_id))
            content = form.save(commit=False)
            content.user = request.user
            content.save()
            return redirect('view_prof')
    else:
        form = EPIF()
    return render(request, 'profs/edit_prof.html', {'form': form})
```

Normal view

```
@login_required
def edit_prof(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EPIF(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('view_prof')
    else:
        form = EPIF()
    return render(request, 'profs/edit_prof.html', {'form': form})
```

When using an SQL update statement in the view, it says there is an error near 'IT'. When using the above view, instead of updating info, it just adds a new set to the user profile table.

**EDIT**

I put quotes around the variables in the SQL statement and it's telling me the data base is locked.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you do not use the Django ORM? This looks like a simple `CustomerUserProfile.objects.filter(id=user_id).update(sex=sex, dob=dob, relationship_stat=r_stat, location=locale, bio=bio)`

Comment: @WillenVanOsem You got it!! Thank you so much, I can't believe it was such a simple thing. So basically, because CustomUserProfile subclasses models.Model, it inherited the .update() attribute? I'm still pretty new to django. You saved me alot of frustration, thank you so much!! p.s I have no idea what the ORM even is, I've been teaching myself through docs and tutorials and haven't come across that until now. Thanks again!

Comment: well models can construct a queryset, and such queryset has an `update(..)` function to update the records it holds, so since `CustomUserProfile` is a model, you indeed can use a lot of Django's logic here.

Comment: That's great, makes life a whole lot easier! Thank you again!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @WillemVanOlsen said I only had to add

```
CustomUserProfile.objects.filter(id=user_id).update(sex=sex, dob=dob, relationship_stat=r_stat, location=locale, bio=bio)
```

before the `form.save()` (without any SQL).